# Angular : declaring properties with let and var

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop

in typescript and javascript we either use let or var to declare a variable. But in angular component we don't use them despite that angular uses typescript. For example

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
   productNumber = 5;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

in the productNumber we didn't use let neither var but it still works. Why is that ?

Comment: It's a `class`. This has nothing to do with Angular in particular.

Comment: but it's a class inside angular and coded in typescript

Comment: productNumber is a property of the class. You can still use let/const inside of methods on the class. Product number could also have a private or public keyword in front of it. Typescript is a superset of javascript.

Comment: I know that i can use let inside the method but I'm talking about using it in the productNumber property itself

Comment: @firas1 So? It's still [just TypeScript syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields). And notice that it is not a variable at all.

Comment: I think it has something to do with traditional javascript being more prototype-based inheritance-wise and Typescript being more object-oriented. That property allows us to refer to it with 'this.propertyName'

Comment: var and let is for declare a temporal variable. When you declare a variable in component really you are declaring a new "property" in the component -think about a component like an Object-. This is the reason you access in your .ts to this variable inside a function of the component using "this", e.g. `this.productNumber `. NOTE: about let and var try to avoid the "var". https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html

Answer (score 4):

`let` and `var` are for making local variables. What you've got in this example isn't a local variable, it's a [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields). They're a different kind of thing, so they have a different kind of syntax.

When you do this:

```
export class Example {
   productNumber = 5;
}
```

It's basically a shorthand for this (which also doesn't use `var` or `let`):

```
export class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.productNumber = 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't a class field also a variable ?

Comment: I've gone through a couple iterations of trying to answer your question, but each answer i've come up with basically turns into nitpicking of definitions, which isn't really useful. So, is it a variable? My answer is "yeah, sure". Stuff gets assigned to other stuff, and in casual conversation i'm ok with calling that a variable. Why do you ask?

Comment: A class field is also a variable, yeah. But its about the scope of the variable. Class field can be used in all functions defined in that class. `let/var` scoped variables can only be used within their "block" (like a function or a function within a function).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable using let or var, javascript allocates a dedicated memory space for the variable. Everytime you write some value into that variable, it actually means that you are writing into that particular memory space. You can create, such variables inside a function(is a local variable) or in a file(is global to that file).

In your case, productNumber is just a class member and you are just telling the typescript compiler that there is a member variable which has default value of 5. It actually gets memory allocation, when you instantiate an object of that class in a file or a function as below.

```
let object1 = new Example(5);
```